# Fetch AWS KMS Asymmetric keys in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

Get AWS KMS Asymmetric RSA_4096 private and public key in Java using SDK2.

Here I need to get Asymmetric keys from KMS. I have written the java code but it's throwing some exception :

```
package com.example;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.KmsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DataKeyPairSpec;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DataKeySpec;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DescribeKeyRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DescribeKeyResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyPairRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.GenerateDataKeyPairResponse;

public class KmsKeys {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = DefaultCredentialsProvider.builder().build();
        KmsClient kmsClient = KmsClient.builder().credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .region(Region.CA_CENTRAL_1).build();
        GenerateDataKeyPairRequest dataKeyPairRequest = GenerateDataKeyPairRequest.builder()
                .keyPairSpec(DataKeyPairSpec.RSA_4096).keyId("xxx").build();
        DescribeKeyRequest describeKeyRequest = DescribeKeyRequest.builder()
                .keyId("xxx").build();
        DescribeKeyResponse describeKey = kmsClient.describeKey(describeKeyRequest);
        GenerateDataKeyPairResponse generateDataKeyPair = kmsClient.generateDataKeyPair(dataKeyPairRequest);
        String privateKey = generateDataKeyPair.privateKeyPlaintext().asUtf8String();
        String publicKey = generateDataKeyPair.publicKey().asUtf8String();
        System.out.println("privateKey : " + privateKey);
        System.out.println("publicKey : " + publicKey);


    }

}
```

Exception I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.InvalidKeyUsageException: You cannot generate a data key pair with an asymmetric CMK (Service: Kms, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 95b51a17-f041-44ea-be67-7df73c98513d)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.DefaultKmsClient.generateDataKeyPair(DefaultKmsClient.java:4174)
    at com.example.KmsKeys.main(KmsKeys.java:21)
```

Is it possible to get Asymmetric keys from kms using aws sdk?
If yes why it's giving me exception here. Please help if someone has ever tried this.